# Перевод массива в текст (без тегов)

Tags: массивы, wordpress

Сайт на wordpress. Есть массив строк, который я преобразую в единую строку (текст):

```
$result = implode("\n", $massivnew);
```

Потом я присваиваю это значение произвольному полю (которое потом идет на вывод).

```
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'resultat', $result);
```

Результат такой:

```
<div>Буря мглою небо кроет,</div><br />
<div>Вихри снежные крутя;</div><br />
<div>То, как зверь, она завоет</div><br />
<div>То заплачет, как дитя,</div><br />
```

Хотя нужен такой:

```
<div>Буря мглою небо кроет,</div> 
<div>Вихри снежные крутя;</div> 
<div>То, как зверь, она завоет,</div> 
<div>То заплачет, как дитя,</div>
```

Я пытался делать так, но не работает:

```
$result2 = ereg_replace ("/\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n/", "", $result);
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'resultat', $result2);
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Зачем все эти explode/implode? В произвольное поле можно записать массив.

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема была в том, что при выводе произволных полей надо не забывать про apply_filters:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resultat', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $result = implode("\n", $massivnew);
> ```

```
$result = implode("", $massivnew);
```

Comment: Да, но в таком случае результат будет следующим:                 
            {<div>Буря мглою небо кроет,</div> <div>Вихри снежные крутя;</div> <div>То, как зверь, она завоет,</div> <div>То заплачет, как дитя,</div> }

Comment: Но ты такой и просил?

Comment: Нет, нужен с переходом строки, но без br

Comment: Собственно такой результат, если бы я этот текст просто поместил в произвольное поле и вывел. Тогда сохраняется переход строки, но нет тегов br

Comment: Нет, не нужен...